# VB not realising a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq

I'm using linq within my VB ASP.Net project to populate a search result. using intersect to compare a list of words that are the query, and a string. Im splitting the string on a space to ensure that two collections are being intersected. but VB is not realising this and throwing the following error.

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Public member 'Count' on type 'String' not found.
```

The Code as it appears in the select statement is as follows

```
MatchCount = keywords.Intersect(IIf(IsNothing(t.TripName), t.tbl_Subject.SubjectName & " in " & t.tbl_City.CityName, t.TripName).ToLower().Split(" ")).Count() / IIf(IsNothing(t.TripName), t.tbl_Subject.SubjectName & " in " & t.tbl_City.CityName, t.TripName).Count
```

apologies for the hard to read nature of it, Its in a select statement so has to be one query. split accross multiple lines it would look like this:

```
Dim name as string = IIf(IsNothing(t.TripName), t.tbl_Subject.SubjectName & " in " & t.tbl_City.CityName, t.TripName)
MatchCount = keywords.Intersect(name.ToLower().Split(" ")).Count()
```

EDIT: - whole, original (not written by me) select statement

```
toReturn.AddRange(results.Select(Function(t) New SearchResult() _
                      With {
                            .MatchCount = keywords.Intersect(If(IsNothing(t.TripName), t.tbl_Subject.SubjectName & " in " & t.tbl_City.CityName, t.TripName).ToLower().Split(" ")).Count() / If(IsNothing(t.TripName), t.tbl_Subject.SubjectName & " in " & t.tbl_City.CityName, t.TripName).Count, _
                            .UID = t.TripID, _
                            .Title = IIf(t.TripName Is Nothing, t.tbl_Subject.SubjectName & " in " & t.tbl_City.CityName, t.TripName), _
                            .Description = t.DescriptionLong.ToString().Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "").Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "").Replace("<strong>", "").Replace("</strong>", "").Replace("<i>", "").Replace("</i>", "").Replace("<em>", "").Replace("</em>", "").Replace("<br>", "").Replace("<br />", ""), _
                            .ImageURL = IIf(t.ImageSub04 Is Nothing, t.tbl_City.ImageThumb, t.ImageSub04),
                            .URL = "/" & t.tbl_Subject.SubjectWebName & "/" & t.tbl_Country.CountryWebName & "/" & _
                                        IIf(t.TripWebName Is Nothing, _
                                        t.tbl_City.CityWebName, _
                                        t.TripWebName) _
                                        & "_trip/",
                            .IsCity = keywords.Contains(t.tbl_City.CityName) Or keywords.Contains(t.tbl_Country.CountryName)
                         }).OrderBy(Function(sr) sr.IsCity).ThenByDescending(Function(sr) sr.MatchCount))
```

Comment: String has a `Length`, not a `Count` property. For whatever reason, the result of `keywords.Intersect` is a string. What is the type of `keywords` and what is the definition of `Intersect`? Are you using `Enumerable.Intersect` or your own version?

Comment: Why don't you use multiple lines and variables to store values? That would be much more readable. Maybe you can abstract your code to the relevant problem without thos `IIF`s(you know that there is an `If`-operator?).

Comment: Enumerable.Intersect, and keywords is a list of string. So the returned type should always be enumerable

Comment: Switch Option Strict On and change `IIf` to `If` to start with. Fixing any errors that get thrown up there might fix your overall problem

Comment: @TimSchmelter +1 - just realised there is *another* call to `Count()` hidden in there

Comment: @TimSchmelter because, as said in my question, its in a select statement, so I cant store variables

Comment: @LiamHT no, it isn't a select statement. It's a plain old expression. Nothing will change if you split it. Right now I see both a `.Count()` and a `.Count`, string concatenations and an obvious conversion to `String` where you though you would get a collection. Please split the lines and check the types of the results. *AND* ensure `Option String On` is enabled to ensure such errors are caught at compile time. Select statements are those found inside a SQL query or those following `select` in a LINQ query.

Comment: With great power (linq) comes great responsibility (not writing a unmanagable page full in one query)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Count()` also on a string, why don't you use `Length` there?

> because, as said in my question, its in a select statement, so I cant
>   store variables

You can even in a query, for example by using anonymous types or (in query syntax) with the `Let` keyword.

In this case i guess that this is what you are trying to do, look how much more readable it is:

```
Dim sResults = From res In results
               Let longTripName = String.Format("{0} in {1}", res.tbl_Subject.SubjectName, res.TripName)
               Let trip = If(res.TripName, longTripName)
               Let tripWords = trip.ToLower().Split(" "c)
               Let matching = keywords.Intersect(tripWords).Count()
               Let matchCount = matching / trip.Length
               Let title = " this is your task "
               Let description = " this is your task "
               Let imageURL = " this is your task "
               Let url = " this is your task "
               Let isCity = True ' also your task '
               Select sr = New SearchResult With {
                   .MatchCount = matchCount,
                   .Title = title,
                   .Description = description,
                   .ImageURL = imageURL,
                   .URL = url,
                   .IsCity = isCity
               }
               Order By sr.IsCity, sr.MatchCount Descending
toReturn.AddRange(sResults)
```

But in general i would recommend to implement an appropriate method or constructor in `SearchResult` which encapsulates the logic and complexity.

Also, since you are using `Split(" ")` and that compiles, you should really change to `Option Strict On`. I guess that you get many compiler errors then which is a good thing since it shows you what you have to fix. Here you have to use `Split(" "c)` instead.

Comment: again, thats not helpful. Because my code is originally in a select statement. ill add the whole statement to the question

Comment: @LiamHT: have a look again. In VB.NET you should benefit ffrom the much more powerful and readable query syntax.

Comment: @LiamHT nothing prevents you from calling a function inside a select statement. Just extract the entire block to a separate function that accepts whatever `t` is and returns `SearchResult` then call it on Select's argument. LINQ even allows you to call this as `results.Select(MyFactoryMethod)` because the parameter and result are infered.